# How to run the split view on iPad using SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, ipad, swiftui

It seems like there would be an easy way to make the good looking iOS app run on an iPad space. One that didn't involve rewriting the SwiftUI app.

The basic `SplitView` & `SplitViewController` issue seems ... well like a poorly thought out problem space...  I've got a basic - display cards with the ContentView - I'd like it to run on iPad... just a bigger viewport...

Any easy way to accomplish this using SwiftUI?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Download the following Apple project https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/fruta_building_a_feature-rich_app_with_swiftui and look up how Navigation is defined between the iPhone, iPad and Mac application. You will find what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm not following you @RolandLariotte I see the link is for the apple Fruta app. 

But look up how navigation is defined... can you tell me more... a file name or something to search for...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So this is how you would setup your iPhone, iPad and mac applications following the [Apple Fruta app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/fruta_building_a_feature-rich_app_with_swiftui) example using Xcode12, for iOS14 and macOS11 as a minimum target.

By using this SwiftUI implementation, you will have the split view that the iPad is using as well as for the mac. Regarding the iPhone, you will have the classic tab bar.

This is a ready to use code, so if you don't need the mac app, just delete the part between the `#else` and `#end`. I implemented it in case other people would find it handy as it is a perfect fit for a multiplatform app project. The code between `#if os(iOS)` and `#else` is for iPhone and iPad.

Look up for the comments I add in the code that explain at which point the split view is being made.

The ContentView that holds the navigation type depending on the device:

```
struct ContentView: View {

  #if os(iOS)
  @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) private var horizontalSizeClass
  #endif

  @ViewBuilder
  var body: some View {
    #if os(iOS)
    if horizontalSizeClass == .compact {
      TabBarNavigationView() // For iPhone
    }
    else {
      SidebarNavigationView() // For iPad
    }
    #else
    SidebarNavigationView() // For mac
      .frame(minWidth: 900, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 500, maxHeight: .infinity)
    #endif
  }
}
```

Then, declare the classic iPhone tab bar with an enumeration of your tabs
(The HomeView can be replace by any of your SwiftUI views):

```
enum TabItem {
  case home
}

struct TabBarNavigationView: View {

  @State private var selection: TabItem = .home

  var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selection) {

      NavigationView {
        HomeView() // Create a SwiftUI HomeView or add your view
      }
      .tabItem {
        Image(systemName: "house")
          .font(.headline)
          .imageScale(.medium) }
      .tag(TabItem.home)
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the view that will hold the iPad and mac classic split view. When having the iPad on portrait mode, your views will be as navigations and when adding it on landscape, your views will be split.

```
struct SidebarNavigationView: View {

  @SceneStorage("selection")
  var selection: String?

  var content: some View {
    List(selection: $selection) {
      NavigationLink(destination: HomeView()) {
        Label(title: { Text("Home") },
              icon: { Image(systemName: "house")
                .font(.headline)
                .imageScale(.medium) })
      }
      .tag(NavigationItem.home)
    }
    .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
  }

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      #if os(iOS)
      content
      #else
      content
        .frame(minWidth: 200, idealWidth: 200, maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .toolbar {
          ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
            Button(action: toggleSidebar ) {
              Image(systemName: "sidebar.left")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            }
          }
        }
      #endif

      // This is the part where the magic happens for the split view.
      // Instead of the Text, add any view you want in place.
      // Play here to see what fits best for you.
      Text("Content List")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)

      #if os(iOS)
      Text("Split view for iPad")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
      #else
      Text("Split view for macOS")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .toolbar { Spacer() }
      #endif
    }
  }
}

extension SidebarNavigationView {
  /// Show or hide the sidebar list in macOS.
  ///
  /// Needed for when the sidebar is hidden from the user   
  /// action as there is a bug in this version of SwiftUI
  /// that block the user to show the sidebar again without
  /// this hack.
  func toggleSidebar() {
    #if os(macOS)
    NSApp
      .keyWindow?
      .firstResponder?
      .tryToPerform(#selector(NSSplitViewController.toggleSidebar(_:)),
                    with: nil)
    #endif
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Roland - I tryied this code and it might be working - but I've run into a "bug" with converting to a TabBar layout... I've got more than 5 options, and the current iOS 13 seems to break after 6 items... found some Cocoapods to deal with TabBar - but they have an issue with GeometryReader crashing...  if it's not one thing - it's your mother... :^)

So I'm currently in a pickel - back to the whiteboard...

Comment: I'm currently not using a Navigation View in the app - I guess I've built my own navigation with Buttons on a welcome page - OK maybe that's dumb - but now that I tried the TabBarNavigation and it's totally hosed beyond 6 items... and my first attempts with NavigationView resulted in infinitly nested Nav Bars.... I resulted to something that works... So now I'm pondering merging something that works with the iPad code above.  I really don't want an iPad Sidebar... I want (don't know the name for the area... the page) the page to display my card images and no sidebar...